# Get thumbnail of *.mov file at 30 sec.?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am develping on app in which i have many videos, when videos are loaded from server to application it shows black screen while loaded from server. so i write following code to get thumbnail of video and set it to my UIView but i want to take thumbnail image of video after 30 sec. screen.
when i need to change in following code to get that.

```
NSURL *vidURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:objAlbum.strVideoURL];
NSLog(@"URL IS : %@",vidURL);
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:vidURL];
UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
[player stop];
[cell2.playVWimage setImage:thumbnail];
```

Comment: i also want to set that thumbnail in myImageView.

Comment: everything is working. i just want to click thumbnail at 30sec. not at 0sec.

Comment: You get a thumbnail at 1.0 seconds, because in your code you say that you want to get the thumbnail at 1.0 seconds. Simply change that!?

Comment: ya i knw. i had tried that by changing value 1.0 but it isn't work.

Comment: So change your Q to what you tried and esp. remove the obvious bug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this,

```
   AVAsset *myAsset    = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoUrl options:nil];
   AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator   assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:myAsset];
   CGImageRef halfWayImage = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:TIME actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];
   UIImage *image;
   image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:halfWayImage scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```